# Does sonar or Tomcat have a cache set somewhere?

Tags: java, tomcat, caching, sonarqube

The Sonar login page take 30-45 seconds to load and then it takes over 1 minute to login. This only happens when the system has not been used in a couple of hours. It speeds up greatly after the first login. We are using Sonar 3.6.1, Java 1.7_update 25, Tomcat 7. What exactly is it doing to make it take so long to pull up the login page? It looks like a caching issue. Any ideas where I could locate the cache setting? Is there another reason for the slowness?

Comment: It's the first time I've heard of this. Are you sure that the machine does not go to sleep after some time? You should check the logs to see anything weird.

Comment: Rather than guessing at what the problem is, use a profiler and find out what the problem is.